# 2GP managed package is not listing under Solutions in partner console

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, 2gp

We created 2GP managed package from our partner business org and also promoted the version we created.

After doing that we linked to our PBO org in the partner console(connect org under technoligies) and org also getting listed under connected org in technologies and here is the link we followed

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/security_review_update_returned.htm

and here is how its getting listed also

[image]

But our solution / managed package is not getting listed here [image] We waited for 4 days also after connecting the PBO org.

We raised case with salesforce also but they are just giving follow this link , that link and so on. We are struggling this with past one month.

So because of this we are not able to link our solution also. Not sure any setting needs to do in PBO org.
Even we tried creating dev org and that also not being listed here.